# Erlang: passing a record into a function?

Tags: function, erlang, record, argument-passing

The following code does compile somewhat with a warning:

```
23> c(passing_records).                                              
passing_records.erl:8: Warning: wrong number of arguments in format call
{ok,passing_records}
```

but when I try to run it I get this error trying to pass variables to a record named `pass`:

```
22> passing_records:record_passing([#pass{arg1=2,name="x",to_go=5}]).
* 1: record pass undefined
```

Heres the code:

```
-module(passing_records).
-export([record_passing/1]).
-record(pass, {arg1 ,
                name="",
                to_go=0}).  

record_passing( #pass{arg1 = ARG1, name = NAME, to_go = TO_GO}) ->
        io:format("~p ~p~n", [ARG1,NAME,TO_GO]).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the `record pass undefined` error is that you need to load the record in the shell with the `rr` command to be able to use it directly.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1386211/113848) for more information.

When I do that, I get to the problem that the compiler is warning about:

```
Eshell V5.9  (abort with ^G)
1> c("/tmp/passing_records", [{outdir, "/tmp/"}]).
c("/tmp/passing_records", [{outdir, "/tmp/"}]).
/tmp/passing_records.erl:8: Warning: wrong number of arguments in format call
{ok,passing_records}
2> rr(passing_records).
[pass]
3> passing_records:record_passing([#pass{arg1=2,name="x",to_go=5}]).
** exception error: no function clause matching 
                    passing_records:record_passing([#pass{
                                                     arg1 = 2,name = "x",
                                                     to_go = 5}]) (/tmp/passing_records.erl, line 7)
4> passing_records:record_passing(#pass{arg1=2,name="x",to_go=5}).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  io:format/3
        called as io:format(<0.24.0>,"~p ~p~n",[2,"x",5])
```

(You're also passing the record in a list, while the function expects just a record; thus the error on line 3.)

Answer (score 1):

As the warning message says, the problem is on line 8:

```
 io:format("~p ~p~n", [ARG1,NAME,TO_GO])
```

You are passing in a list of three arguments to the format string: ARG1, NAME, TO_GO, but the format string only uses two of them (there are only two ~p). It has nothing to do with records.

Comment: I fixed it to this `io:format("~p ~p ~p~n", [ARG1,NAME,TO_GO]). ` but I still get the error running it? `passing_records:record_passing([#pass{arg1=2,name="x",to_go=5}]).
* 1: record pass undefined`